# iOS8 behavior on nested navigation controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My app has a top level navigation controller. It navigates between different pages and displays a navigation panel on top, as usual. One of those pages is a tab controller with 3 tabs. Each tab has its own navigation controllers because while being in a tab I need to open a new page pushing on top of that tab content (tab bar will still be visible). My problem: the "inner" navigation works fine, pushes pages and so on, but it cannot "take control" over the navigation panel on top of the screen. This panel is still displaying the global page navigation, while I want to show the "inner" navigation and, if inner has no history, then the global navigation. By saying "show navigation" I mean just the back button.

**Rationale:** The app has a split view controller on top level - it becomes a simple navigation controller for compact sizes. It is navigating through different pages and one of those pages comes out to be a media player/selector (like the iOS built-in Music app). The media selector is a tab controller with 3 tabs for filtering media, suppose its just like the Music app - songs, artists, albums. When you switch to artists tab you can see a table of artists. Clicking on one of them will open a list of songs for that artist, just like in the Music app. The new filtered page is pushed normally but the navigation panel on top of the screen is still showing the global navigation. I want to merge this two navigations so need a way to take over the control of this panel when needed. Seems like it ignore the nested navigation's back logic or I didn't find a nice way to do it. Suppose you should put the iOS Music app in a split view (or navigation) controller and it is just one of the global screens, but still needs a nice navigation logic when filtering tracks.

Comment: You need to set the outer navigation controller's `navigationBarHidden` to `YES` when appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want here.

You can write a bit of extra code to determine what the back button does in the global navigator. It amounts to replacing the built-in back button with an identical - but which calls your own method - button.

Then you can deal with it with whatever is appropriate (whether your inner navigator is showing, etc).

The second way is to hide the outer navigation controller's navigation bar when you are about to show the inner navigation bar, as @Paulw11 said in the comment. You should be able to get seamless results either way.